# Swift - How to get video dimension?

Tags: ios, swift, video, size

I am working on a video editing app where each video gets squared in such a way that no portion of the video gets cropped.For this, in case of portrait video, it contains black portion on left & right and for landscape video, it contains black portion on top & bottom side of the video. Black portions are part of the video, they are not for `AVPlayerViewController`. Here is the sample, [image]

I need to cover these black portions with some `CALayers`.

> What will be the frame(**CGRect**) of the `CALayer`?

I am getting the video dimension with `naturalSize` property which includes the black portions.

> Is there any way to get the video dimension without the black portions?**(I mean the dimension of actual video content)** or
>   is there any way to get the `CGRect` of black area of the video?

Comment: Have I understood you correctly? Do u need aspect ratio of your video?

Comment: no... aspect ratio won't help me to solve the problem

Comment: @pigeon_39 have you got the solution..please help me I stuck on the same issue.

Comment: sorry bro, I didn't get the solution :( @Kapil Maheshwari

Comment: no issue will post if I found any :)

Comment: @KapilMaheshwari found any solution?

Answer (score 54):

```
func initAspectRatioOfVideo(with fileURL: URL) -> Double {
  let resolution = resolutionForLocalVideo(url: fileURL)
  guard let width = resolution?.width, let height = resolution?.height else {
     return 0
  }
  return Double(height / width)
}

private func resolutionForLocalVideo(url: URL) -> CGSize? {
    guard let track = AVURLAsset(url: url).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
   let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
   return CGSize(width: abs(size.width), height: abs(size.height))
}
```

Comment: this is amazing. thanks a lot. apparently just using "natural size" doesn't work but your code is great! thanks!

Comment: @RoiMulia I don't remember actually. I think it should. You can give it a try

Comment: :/ my bad i'm facing the same problem with objective-C using the (natural size + preferredTransform) it always returns an obsolete value !  (with remote video)

Comment: @VladPulichev hello. Thanks for answer. Do you know why for this url `https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/streaming/examples/bipbop_adv_example_hevc/master.m3u8` always get `nil`? I also check all another media types (audio, metadata etc), but have the same result - `nil`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. first is returning nil always.

Comment: When I try this, the Bundle file works fine, but the files in the Documents directory always return nil. Is there a solution?

Comment: This is returning the wrong information for height + width

Answer (score 5):

This is a more concise version of [Vlad Pulichev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879386/swift-how-to-get-video-dimension/44879602#44879602).

```
var aspectRatio: CGFloat! // use the function to assign your variable

func getVideoResolution(url: String) -> CGFloat? {
    guard let track = AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!).tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
    let size = track.naturalSize.applying(track.preferredTransform)
    return abs(size.height) / abs(size.width)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**~New**

```
func getVideoResolution(url: String) async throws -> CGSize? {
        guard let track = try await AVURLAsset(url: URL(string: url)!).loadTracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video).first else { return nil }
        let size = try await track.load(.naturalSize).applying(track.load(.preferredTransform))
        return size
}
```