# Media Meta Data Retrieval in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mobile-development

In my Xamarin.Forms app, I want to use a DependencyService for each platform to get meta data about local media files such as Height, Width and Rotation. Here is how I do it in Android:

```
public double ReturnVideoHeight(string mediaFilePath)
        {
            MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            reader.SetDataSource(mediaFilePath);

            var str = reader.ExtractMetadata(MetadataKey.VideoHeight);

            if (double.TryParse(str, out double num))
            {
                return num;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public double ReturnVideoWidth(string mediaFilePath)
        {
            MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            reader.SetDataSource(mediaFilePath);

            var str = reader.ExtractMetadata(MetadataKey.VideoWidth);

            if (double.TryParse(str, out double num))
            {
                return num;
            }
            return -1;   

        }

        public string ReturnVideoRotation(string mediaFilePath)
        {
            MediaMetadataRetriever reader = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            reader.SetDataSource(mediaFilePath);

            return reader.ExtractMetadata(MetadataKey.VideoRotation);
        }
```

I can't seem to find iOS libraries to accomplish the same thing. How could I go about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879386/swift-how-to-get-video-dimension

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've used it to help me get the height/width but unfortunately I can't find a way to get the rotation.

Comment: You could convert it to `AVAsset` first,then get the width,height and rotation from the `AVAsset`.