# Remove black layouts from VideoPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

I use AVPlayer to play video on my SwiftUI project but I notice the video has black layouts around it. Here is how it looks like:

[image]

Here is the code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    public var body: some View {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url:  URL(string: "https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/360/Big_Buck_Bunny_360_10s_1MB.mp4")!))
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .frame(height: 350)
    }
}
```

How do I remove the black layout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879386/swift-how-to-get-video-dimension